# What is at (0,0) of the Star Trek quadrant system?

Tags: star-trek

The Star Trek quadrant system divides the Milky Way into four sections. What is at (0,0) or (0,0,0) if need be? Have astronomers tried to estimate where these zero coordinates would be?

Comment: Probably a black hole.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, to quote [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Coordinates):

> According to [Star Trek Maps](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Maps), the XYZ spatial coordinates 0,0,0 used by the Federation are those of a central navigation beacon located near the core worlds of the Federation. The galactic XYZ values are in a grid in relation to this central beacon. Units in the grid are parsecs. The first value X is the distance towards (positive) or away from (negative) the center of the galaxy. The second value Y is the distance towards the left "Alpha Quadrant" direction (positive) or the right "Beta Quadrant" direction (negative). The third value Z is the distance in the galactic north direction upwards (positive) or galactic south downwards (negative) away from the galactic plane.

Comment: Was there such a coordinate reference in some ST episode or movie that placed Earth at that coordinance?

Comment: I WANT to say I remember 1, 1, 1 being Earth in one of the episodes or movies where the Borg attacked, but I don't have copies handy to watch.  They may not have been consistent across all the franchise versions, tho.

Comment: @KHW Sector 0,0,1 is the terran system.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz - That could be what I'm remembering.  Do you know where that is referenced?

Comment: @KHW Numerous episodes including The Best of Both Worlds.

Comment: If that's the case, Delta Quadrant should exist in Federation space..

Comment: It's a shame they didn't just use polar coordinates.

Answer (score -1):

Using a system as a beacon would have the universe shift around if quite annoyingly after many, many years.

Regardless the coordinates map, roughly, to Earth.